# Read a sector to address zero

Tags: operating-system, bootstrapping

```
%include "init.inc"

[org 0x0]
[bits 16]

jmp 0x07C0:start_boot

start_boot:
    mov ax, cs
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax

load_setup:
    mov ax, SETUP_SEG
    mov es, ax
    xor bx, bx

    mov ah, 2           ; copy data to es:bx from disk.
    mov al, 1           ; read a sector.
    mov ch, 0           ; cylinder 0
    mov cl, 2           ; read data since sector 2.
    mov dh, 0           ; Head  = 0
    mov dl, 0           ; Drive = 0
    int 0x13            ; BIOS call.

    jc load_setup

    lea si, [msg_load_setup]
    call print

    jmp $

print:
print_beg:
    mov ax, 0xB800
    mov es, ax
    xor di, di

print_msg:
    mov al, byte [si]
    mov byte [es:di], al
    or al, al
    jz print_end
    inc di
    mov byte [es:di], BG_TEXT_COLOR
    inc di
    inc si
    jmp print_msg

print_end:
    ret

msg_load_setup db "Loading setup.bin was completed." , 0

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```

I want to load setup.bin to memory address zero. So, I input 0 value to es register (SETUP_SEG = 0). bx, too. But it didn't work. then, I have a question about this issue. My test is below.

SETUP_SEG's value 
0x0000 : fail 
0x0010 : success 
0x0020 : fail 
0x0030 : fail 
0x0040 : fail 
0x0050 : success

I can't understand why this situation was happened. All test was carried out on VMware. Does anyone have an idea ?

Comment: VMware running what?  That looks like 16-bit real-mode code:(

Comment: Sorry, I edited all bootstrap code above. Yes, 16-bit real mode code. running that code on VMware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is your problem, but your trying to load `setup.bin` in the [Real Mode IVT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_vector_table/) (Interrupt Vector Table). The IVT contains the location of each interrupt, so I'm assuming that your boatloader is overwriting them when it loads `setup.bin` into memory! Interrupts can be sneaky and tricky, since they **can** be called even if you **didn't** call them. Any interrupt vector you overwrote will likely cause *undefined behavior* when called, which **will** cause some problems.

I suggest setting `SETUP_SEG` to a higher number like 0x2000 or 0x3000, but the lowest you could **safely** go is 0x07E0. The [Osdev Wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org/Memory_Map_%28x86%29#Overview) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conventional_memory) have some helpful information on conventional memory and memory mapping.

I hope this helps!